# XDK - html5 tag video, autoplay and loop ignored by Android

Tags: html5-video, intel-xdk

I am developing a simple application in XDK IBM to run a video in a android device.

The problem is, after built, the video dont autoplay and dont do the loop.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Blank Hybrid App Project Template</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <style>
            @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }                           @viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }
            @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }                                    @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    </head> 
    <body>
        <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="true" loop="true"> 
            <source src="assets/1234.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' id="src" autostart="true">
        </video>

        <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="xhr.js"></script>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init-app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init-dev.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I afraid this problem seem to be a XDK issue. In the debug it works as expected. I tested the APk in 2 smartphones and in the MK808.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" id="video"> 
    <source src="assets/12345.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' id="src" autostart="true">
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var video = document.getElementById("video");     
    video.loop = false; 
    video.addEventListener('ended', function() { video.currentTime=0.1; video.play(); }, false);
    video.play();
</script>
```